# akeneo pim ce 4.0 install error on docker desktop for windows

Tags: docker, desktop, akeneo, pim

I am trying to install akeneo pim ce 4.0 on docker desktop for windows using the standard ce package with no changes; however, when i run "make prod" as per install instructions, it fails when trying to run "wait_docker_up.sh" in the makefile, with "file not found error" but it is not clear to me which file cannot be found. please can anyone assist - thanks (powershell cmd log reproduced below):

PS C:\ohp\pim\pim-community-standard> .\make prod
C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard/make dependencies
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for`dependencies'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard'
C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard/make pim-prod
make[1]: Entering directory`C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard'
C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard/make up
make[2]: Entering directory `C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard'
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphan
pim-community-standard_object-storage_1 is up-to-date
Starting pim-community-standard_blackfire_1 ...
pim-community-standard_elasticsearch_1 is up-to-date
Starting pim-community-standard_php_1       ...
Starting pim-community-standard_node_1      ...
pim-community-standard_selenium_1 is up-to-date
Starting pim-community-standard_blackfire_1 ... done                                                                                                                                                     Starting pim-community-standard_php_1       ... done                                                                                                                                                     Starting pim-community-standard_node_1      ... done                                                                                                                                                     make[2]: Leaving directory`C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard' docker/wait_docker_up.sh

**process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, env bash C:\ohp\pim\pim-community-standard\docker\wait_docker_up.sh, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.**

make[1]: *** [pim-prod] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/ohp/pim/pim-community-standard'
make: *** [prod] Error 2
PS C:\ohp\pim\pim-community-standard>

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue because it tries to run a bash script `wait_docker_up.sh` in a window environment. The goal of this script is to wait until the services started in the containers are up and ready.

Actually, Akeneo docker setup does not support windows platform.

If you want to do so, I would recommend you to install bash in windows. There is no  guarantee that it will work exactly the same way though.

Comment: i am actually installing akeneo in mobylimux environment which comes with docker desktop for windows. i have been using akeneo pim ce 3.2 for a whie on the same platform and it works just fine - the difference with version 3.2 install though, is that it does not use .sh scripts and the entire installation is done using docker-compose commands. i have also tried to install on ubuntu/debian on windows but the message i got from installer program was to wait until the windows WSL2 kernel release (i understand it due in the next few days) - i will try it then. thanks